# Disable IIS / ASP.NET 4.0 automatic friendly URLs

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-routing

for some reason I have not yet found, IIS or ASP.NET 4.0 automatically maps requests to directories such as

`/en/my-lovely-test-page/`

to

`/en/my-lovely-test-page.aspx`

I'm sure this is meant to be an improvement for "friendlier URLs", however I really want to stick with my .aspx URLs and do not want secondary "friendly" URLs pointing to the same page.

How can I completely disable this behavior in IIS / ASP.NET, or better, disable any "smart" mappings I'm not yet aware of? Thank you!

Comment: Do you have an IIS add-ons installed through Windows Platform Installer?

Comment: No, there are no IIS add-ons installed through platform installer (at least nothing "special" - all IIS systems, even on my Windows 7 workstation, show this behavior)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you could use an ignore route in the global.asax

Something like:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*allaspx}", new {allaspx=@".*\.aspx(/.*)?"});
```

Should send all .aspx pages through the normal route

Comment: I don't want .aspx pages to be sent through the normal route. I want directory requests not to be handled by aspx files in the parent folder.